# Bootstrap Tags Input with Typeahead Predefined item from the list

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound, bootstrap-tags-input

I have question regarding predefining item on the list in bootstrap tags input.
For example.
var city_list = ['Sumatra', 'Jawa', 'Sulawesi']
var city_choosen = ['Sumatra']

When the page open, I would like to predefine the input with apple, but in documentation the method .add cause duplication on 'Sumatra'.
I want to define it from the existing list, not add a new one.

Thank you.

```
var tagInput = $('#inputCity');
    tagInput.tagsinput({
        itemValue: 'id',
        itemText: 'name',
        typeaheadjs: {
            autoselect: true,
            name: 'cities',
            displayKey: 'name',
            source: cities.ttAdapter()
        }
    })

tagInput.tagsinput('add', {"id":  2, 'name': "Sumatra Utara"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error's solution. 
In my php code, I put quote inside the id value, so it will get duplicate, for example: 2 and '2'.